# Ошибка: выход за пределы массива

Tags: python

При выполнении следующего кода выдаётся ошибка 'list index out of range':

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
mult = 1
max1 = 0
a = []
for i in range(m,n+1):
    a.append(i)
    while a[i] > 0:
        if a[i]%10 != 0:
            if  mult * (a[i]%10) % 4 == 0 and a[i] > max1:
                 max1 = a[i]
print (max1)
```

Помогите найти ошибку в коде.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что в строке `a.append(i)` вы добавляете i-й элемент в пустой список, а потом сразу же, в строке `while a[i] > 0` пытаетесь найти в этом списке элемент с **индексом** `i`. Но т.к. на данный момент в списке только один элемент, то он не найдется ни по какому индексу, кроме `0`